# How can I put strings in array starting from 0 index

Tags: php, arrays

hello I have a string like this 
"*HQ,6170929875,V1,185905,A,3127.3354,N,07307.6954,E,000.09,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185915,A,3127.3365,N,07307.6951,E,002.30,018,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185925,A,3127.3372,N,07307.6952,E,000.76,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185935,A,3127.3369,N,07307.6947,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185945,A,3127.3371,N,07307.6951,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185955,A,3127.3377,N,07307.6952,E,000.21,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190005,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6950,E,000.17,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190015,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6953,E,000.07,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190025,A,3127.3375,N,07307.6955,E,000.59,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190035,A,3127.3373,N,07307.6944,E,000.35,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190045,A,3127.3378,N,07307.6950,E,000.23,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190055,A,3127.3381,N,07307.6955,E,000.32,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#"

I want to put all these values in an array. so I did this

```
$array = explode("*",$str);
```

Now when i printed the array the data is

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185905,A,3127.3354,N,07307.6954,E,000.09,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [2] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185915,A,3127.3365,N,07307.6951,E,002.30,018,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [3] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185925,A,3127.3372,N,07307.6952,E,000.76,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [4] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185935,A,3127.3369,N,07307.6947,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [5] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185945,A,3127.3371,N,07307.6951,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [6] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185955,A,3127.3377,N,07307.6952,E,000.21,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [7] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190005,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6950,E,000.17,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [8] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190015,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6953,E,000.07,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [9] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190025,A,3127.3375,N,07307.6955,E,000.59,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [10] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190035,A,3127.3373,N,07307.6944,E,000.35,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [11] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190045,A,3127.3378,N,07307.6950,E,000.23,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [12] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190055,A,3127.3381,N,07307.6955,E,000.32,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
)
```

0 index is empty. I want to start the array from 0 index. Please help. what I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first element of your array is blank because your string begins with *. To solve this simply do:

```
$str = "*HQ,6170929875,V1,185905,A,3127.3354,N,07307.6954,E,000.09,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185915,A,3127.3365,N,07307.6951,E,002.30,018,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185925,A,3127.3372,N,07307.6952,E,000.76,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185935,A,3127.3369,N,07307.6947,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185945,A,3127.3371,N,07307.6951,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185955,A,3127.3377,N,07307.6952,E,000.21,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190005,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6950,E,000.17,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190015,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6953,E,000.07,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190025,A,3127.3375,N,07307.6955,E,000.59,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190035,A,3127.3373,N,07307.6944,E,000.35,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190045,A,3127.3378,N,07307.6950,E,000.23,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190055,A,3127.3381,N,07307.6955,E,000.32,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#";

$arr = explode('*', $str);
array_shift($arr);

print_r($arr);
```

Which produces:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185905,A,3127.3354,N,07307.6954,E,000.09,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [1] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185915,A,3127.3365,N,07307.6951,E,002.30,018,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [2] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185925,A,3127.3372,N,07307.6952,E,000.76,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [3] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185935,A,3127.3369,N,07307.6947,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [4] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185945,A,3127.3371,N,07307.6951,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [5] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185955,A,3127.3377,N,07307.6952,E,000.21,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [6] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190005,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6950,E,000.17,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [7] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190015,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6953,E,000.07,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [8] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190025,A,3127.3375,N,07307.6955,E,000.59,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [9] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190035,A,3127.3373,N,07307.6944,E,000.35,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [10] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190045,A,3127.3378,N,07307.6950,E,000.23,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [11] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190055,A,3127.3381,N,07307.6955,E,000.32,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass it to `array_filter` to remove first child (index 0). It happen because you have * on first part of string. Exploding by * delimiter mean zero string on first value.

Something like:

```
$array = explode("*",$str);
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It works but as in my question I want the array to start from 0 index so for me @D. Simmons solution works. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring simply because you have a "*" character at the start of the string

```
*HQ,6170929875,V1,185905,A,3127.3354,N,07307.6954,E,000.09,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*....
```

If you always have that character at the start of the string, you will always have an empty index 0 in your resultant array - you need to either remove the first character before exploding the string or the first item of the array.

Answer (score 0):

You might use a combination of [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove the empty values and [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) to reindex the array to start from 0:

```
$str = "*HQ,6170929875,V1,185905,A,3127.3354,N,07307.6954,E,000.09,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185915,A,3127.3365,N,07307.6951,E,002.30,018,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185925,A,3127.3372,N,07307.6952,E,000.76,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185935,A,3127.3369,N,07307.6947,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185945,A,3127.3371,N,07307.6951,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,185955,A,3127.3377,N,07307.6952,E,000.21,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190005,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6950,E,000.17,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190015,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6953,E,000.07,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190025,A,3127.3375,N,07307.6955,E,000.59,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190035,A,3127.3373,N,07307.6944,E,000.35,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190045,A,3127.3378,N,07307.6950,E,000.23,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#*HQ,6170929875,V1,190055,A,3127.3381,N,07307.6955,E,000.32,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#";

print_r(array_values(array_filter(explode("*", $str))));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185905,A,3127.3354,N,07307.6954,E,000.09,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [1] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185915,A,3127.3365,N,07307.6951,E,002.30,018,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [2] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185925,A,3127.3372,N,07307.6952,E,000.76,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [3] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185935,A,3127.3369,N,07307.6947,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [4] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185945,A,3127.3371,N,07307.6951,E,000.27,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [5] => HQ,6170929875,V1,185955,A,3127.3377,N,07307.6952,E,000.21,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [6] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190005,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6950,E,000.17,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [7] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190015,A,3127.3376,N,07307.6953,E,000.07,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [8] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190025,A,3127.3375,N,07307.6955,E,000.59,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [9] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190035,A,3127.3373,N,07307.6944,E,000.35,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [10] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190045,A,3127.3378,N,07307.6950,E,000.23,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
    [11] => HQ,6170929875,V1,190055,A,3127.3381,N,07307.6955,E,000.32,000,060718,FFFFB9FF,410,04,03104,32566#
)
```